# Determining biggest number in array

Tags: java, arrays

Can someone explain this code to me? I have an array of integers. The code is supposed to determine which number is the biggest, but I don´t understand the if-statement in this context.

```
int max = 0; 
for(int i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++) {
        if(max < testArray[i]) {
            max = testArray[i];
        }
}
```

Comment: Well, try to describe the if statement in words: "if max is smaller than the array element, then the array element is the new max value".

Comment: you iterate the array item by item and remember the currently biggest item during your iteration. so whenever you see an item that is bigger than what you currently know, you update your variable. at the end, you have the biggest element.

Comment: Note that the above code only works if all the numbers in testArray are non-negative. If they were all negative, say `-1 -3 -17 -42`, then `max` would stay at 0 even though `-1` was the max.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the loop we declare an integer called `max`. This variable will represent the highest value we have found. We then start a for-loop that iterates over every element of the array. For every value, we compare it to our `max` variable. If `max` is lower than the value we are inspecting then the value is the highest value we have found so far, so we assign the value to the `max` variable. After we have iterated over the entire array, the `max` variable will contain the highest value we have found.

```
int max = 0; // A variable that represents the highest value we have found
for(int i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++) {
        if(max < testArray[i]) { // If max is lower than the current value...
            max = testArray[i]; // ...assign the current value to max
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

first let's create array `[10, 100, 25, 57, 63, 96]` and start our loop
the max = 0 where the first int will be 10
the if will test is 0 < 10 true it will go and make the max = 10
the second time will check if the 10 < 100 which is true it will do the statement and max will be 100
then the third will check if 100 < 25 which is false and keep until the end of loop